# Fixed position image not being display on old blackberrys

Tags: html, css

I have an image (that I'm adding to a page with javascript) I want to display at the bottom of my screen (not at the bottom of the content ).

Everything seems to work fine except for older blackberry's. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

In my html I have

```
<div id="sticky" class="banner-sticky" style="position: fixed;">
</div>
```

and in my css I have

```
.banner-sticky {
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
background: rgb(0, 0, 0) transparent;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
/*  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000);
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000)";*/
-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
}

.advert-img {
width: 90%
height: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {
.advert-img {
width: 90%
}
}

@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 320px),
only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 320px),
only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1)    and (min-width: 320px),
only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 320px),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi) and (min-width: 320px),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx)  and (min-width: 320px) { 
.advert-img {
width: 90%
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {

.advert-img {
width: 50%
}

}

@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 700px),
only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 700px),
only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1)    and (min-width: 700px),
only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 700px),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi) and (min-width: 700px),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx)  and (min-width: 700px) { 

.advert-img {
width: 50%
}

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1300px) {

.advert-img {
width: 30%
}

}

@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 1300px),
only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 1300px),
only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1)    and (min-width: 1300px),
only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 1300px),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi) and (min-width: 1300px),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx)  and (min-width: 1300px) { 

.advert-img {
width: 30%
}

}
```

The generated html after the javascript does its thing:

```
<div style="position: fixed;" class="banner-sticky" id="sticky">
<a href="http://ad.vic-m.co:80/landingpage?pr=21&amp;ar=GoM;ht=245" id="ad-link">
<span id="banner-ad"><img src="http://ad.vic-m.co:8080/AdService/fileHandleAction?file=7A10B19B-2E51-4CCE-AB6A-319C382B4AA8" class="advert-img">
</span>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: What older blackberries do, where they show the banner? Possible problem can be in `bottom: 2.5px`. Some of browsers can this value ignore as a nonsense (what they should do with a half-pixels?)

Comment: Its not being displayed at all. I thought maybe older blackberry browsers dont support fixed positions? or I have to add position: relative the the containing div maybe?

Comment: #spuggy: blackberry should support fixed position, http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-fixed. Relative position will be ignored when there is fixed (it works with absolute only). What about `2.5px`, have you tried to set just `2px`?

Comment: yes I've removed the 2.5px and replaced it with 0px.

Comment: Can you show more of your CSS, please? What about #sticky styles?

Comment: I've added the rest of the css and some generated html

Comment: if dosen't work only on blackberry, check if there are image format compatibility restriction with old blackberries